# Truffle Error: invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-test

I'm trying to deploy and test the smart contracts on the Goerli network using Truffle. While migrating getting below error.

```
Contract: Simple Storage Test suite
       Simple Storage Set
         Should check that the Value is updated successfully:
       Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined

 Contract: Simple Storage Test suite
       "after each" hook: after test for "Should check that the Value is updated successfully":
     Error: invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix
```

**Truffle Version**
Truffle v5.1.19 (core: 5.1.19)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v12.16.1
Web3.js v1.2.1

Comment: Can i see the code where you deploy your contract please?

Comment: `
"use strict";

const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require('SimpleStorage');

module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {
  const [owner] = accounts;
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, {
    from: owner
  });
};
`

Comment: @FLASH Can you add more code so we can see what the test is doing? The problem may be that a getter is returning invalid answer.

Comment: The error is at the end of one of your truffle tests.

Comment: check [here](https://pastebin.com/TZQmNHh0)

Comment: I would guess that `accounts === []` when you switch from Ganache (or whatever private network you use for testing) to Goerli (a public network). If `accounts === []`, then `accounts[0]` is undefined, which means that `owner` is undefined. You can check whether or not this is the case by printing `owner` (or `accounts`).

Comment: @goodvibration What kind of error? I'm getting these errors only on Goerli. on Ganache it is working fine. And, I'm getting the correct owner address. It's not undefined

Comment: So `owner` is a valid address when you run your test on Goerli?